# How to use `hg cat` from an empty working directory?

Tags: mercurial

I have a repo located at x:/projects/repo1. The working directory has been emptied using `hg update null`.  I want to extract the latest version of some files from there to a local directory.

I tried this:

```
x:\projects\repo1> hg cat -o c:\sql\%s scripts\*.sql -r tip
```

I get this error:

```
scripts\*.sql: No such file in rev 14f07c26178b
```

The same command works fine if the working directory is not empty. Is there a good reason why this does not work? Or do you know another way of extract some files from there to a local directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `hg cat` command is for single files.  If you want multiple files use the `hg archive` command, which makes zipfiles or directories full of files.  Here's your command:

```
x:\projects\repo1> hg archive --include scripts\*.sql -r tip c:\sql
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `hg cat` doesn't support wildcard symbols in paths. So you should use the full file name:

```
hg cat -r tip scripts/foo.sql
```

When your working copy is up to date with the `tip` revision, your shell does wildcard substitution for you.

The `hg manifest` command also might be helpful for getting tracked file listings.

Comment: This is useful. However, I don't know the name of the files I want to extract. I cant list them using `hg manifest` or `hg status --all` because both commands don't work well either on an empty working directory.

Comment: @Sly `hg manifest` has the `-r` option to specify the revision you want to see.

Comment: The windows shell does not expand wildcards, the application does.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is to your comment on [Andrey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322207/how-to-use-hg-cat-from-an-empty-working-directory/3322353#3322353):

`hg manifest` takes a `--rev` argument that you can use to see the list of all files in your repository:

```
hg manifest --rev tip
```

To get the list of files matching a pattern at the tip, use:

```
hg stat --all --include *.sql --rev tip --no-status
hg stat -A -I *.sql --rev tip -n                    # using abbreviations.
```

From there you could redirect the output to a file and edit each line into a `hg cat` command like in your original question.  It appears (to me, at least, having done some experimentation) that `hg cat` uses the contents of the working directory -- rather than the contents of the repository at the revision specified -- for glob-matching, so once you know the exact name of the file, you can `hg cat` it at any revision.