# Mercurial: get contents of a specific revision of a file

Tags: mercurial

I need to get contents of a specific revision/node of a file in a local repository and write it to a temporary file.

I know it is possible to do through the internal Mercurial API.

Is there a built-in command or an extension?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`hg cat`](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#cat):

```
hg cat -r revisionid filename > tmpfile
```

Comment: Note that for multiple files, you have `hg archive`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322207/how-to-use-hg-cat-from-an-empty-working-directory/3323084#3323084

Comment: Thank you. Why on Earth could not I find the answer with Google?

Comment: There is also an -o option which can be used instead of stdout redirect. I suppose it is faster. Am I right?

Comment: @eye: yes you can use the `-o` option to avoid the shell redirection.

Answer (score 2):

The fastest, large and/or binary file friendly way to do this is:

```
hg cat -r revisionid repoRelativeFilePath -o tempFilePath
```

The tempFilePath, unless absolutely rooted (ex. 'C:\') will be relative to the repo's root